# csrftoken cookie fails security test - Missing Flags

Tags: django, django-csrf

I am getting a security error (from Pentest-Tools) saying that the "Secure" and "HttpOnly" flags are missing in my Django project, and not quite sure how to remedy.

I set the cooke with the following in my template

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

I've read you need to set these flags in the headers, but not sure if that's the resolution.

What is the way to set the `Secure` and `HttpOnly` flags?

Answer (score 0):

On your settings.py:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

If you want to read more, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071862/django-sessionid-cookie-is-this-a-security-failure) question goes into detail about these.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Will read up on the question. Just added the vals to settings.py as well. Hopefully that's the fix.